# How to open file for writing?

Tags: dart, dart-io

I'm trying to open and write to a file using Dart's IO library.

I have this code:

```
File file = File("text.txt");
RandomAccessFile raf = file.openSync();
raf.writeStringSync("A string!");
```

Now when doing this I get the following error in the console:

```
(OS Error: Access is denied., errno = 5)
```

So file is not opened for writing, and I'm looking here: [open method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/File/open.html), and can't figure out how to use `open` or `openSync` to get `RandomAccessFile` I can write to.

It says I need to use [write constant](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/FileMode/write-constant.html) to do that but just can't figure out how?
If I try to create [FileMode](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/FileMode-class.html) and add it to `open` method as an argument I get an error saying:

```
Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
```

So `open` and `openSync` methods can't take any arguments, how would one use `FileMode`, and `open` method to open a file that is ready for writing? So I need to get `RandomAccessFile` that is in writing mode? And by default its only in read mode? I'm not trying to use `writeString` or `writeStringSync`, I know those methods exist, but I'm interested in how is this done using `open` and `openSync` methods that return `RandomAccessFile`!

Update:

Comment: If all what you need is write to a file there are examples written in the api docs https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/File-class.html

Comment: Thanks Mattia, I have seen these examples, but I'm going through all methods now as I learn Dart. I can see we could use openWrite method to open file ready for writing, but it returns IOSink, I'm interested to see how to write to a file using open or openSync methods that returns RandomAccessFile. And how to use FileMode class? Also, if I would like to append some text to a file, I would have to use FileMode class as there is no openAppend method as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error:

> Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.

because the [openSync](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/File/openSync.html) method has no positional arguments, but just one named parameter (`mode`).
So to fix your code you must add it:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.append); //Or whatever mode you'd to apply
```

Having said that, there are several other ways to write to a file, most of them listed in the docs:

- [writeString](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/File/writeAsString.html) or [writeStringSync](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/File/writeAsStringSync.html), I'd suggest these if what you need is just to write once to a file.
- [openWrite](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/File/openWrite.html), which returns a `Stream` that can be written in order to write to the file.

(All of these methods have a [FileMode](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/FileMode-class.html) `mode` named parameter)

Comment: Thank you one more time Mattia! So its "positional arguments" and "named paramteres" that confused me! Thanks again!